# What's the probability that the sum of the units of a random number from 1 to 999999 is equal to 9?

Tags: probability, elementary-number-theory

If we pick a random number from 1 to 999,999 and sum up their units till we get a value between 0 to 9, what's the probability that the final value we get is 9?

example 1: the number 185047 is 1+8+5+0+4+7=25, 2+5=7 so the final answer is 7.

I noticed we can use a bit of mod 9, where if a number has a sum of 9 you can "discard" it from the next sum,

example 2: the number 998899 is 9+9+8+8+9+9=52, 5+2=7 but we can also throw out all the multiples of 9 and realize that 8+8=16, 1+6=7 which is the same answer.

example 3: the number 144817 is 1+4+4+8+1+7=25 which is 7, but we can also add up 1+4+4=9 and 1+8=9 with the last digit being 7, so if we discard the nine's we get our answer to be 7.

so what is the probability that a random chosen number between 1 and 999,999

Comment: well, what is a property common to all numbers that ends up in 9?

Comment: By units, do you mean digits?

Comment: You can't have the sum of the digits ever equaling $0$.  So, your question is equivalent to asking how many numbers are there, from $(1)$ through $(999,999)$ that happen to be a multiple of $(9)$.

Comment: @user2661923 are there 11111 multiples of 9 in 999,999?

Comment: Is this not just a fancy way of asking how many multiples of 9 are there between 1 and 999,999 (inclusive). This just gives 111,111

Comment: @Arizus so what's the probability? 1/111,111?

Comment: What you (probably) mean is the digital root. The digital root of a positive integer $n$ is just $n\mod 9$ unless $9\mid n$ , in which case it is $9$. Thus, the condition is simply that your random number is divisible by $9$ which has of course probability $\frac{1}{9}$

Comment: @Peter so the probability of a number randomly chosen from 1 to 999,999/being a divisible by 9, is 1/9?